# Mysql Date Column Error during insertion from Java

Tags: java, mysql, runtime-error

I want to insert a data using JDBC, whenever I execute the program then it shows me some Mysql error:

**Insert statement:**

```
String sql = "INSERT into books(name, isbn, author, category, desc, published) VALUES('"+name+"','"+isbn+"','"+author+"','"+category+"', '"+desc+"','"+book_published+"')";
```

**I am trying to convert the string to date here using :**

```
String yr = year.getSelectedItem().toString();
String mn = month.getSelectedItem().toString();
String dy = day.getSelectedItem().toString();
String book_date = yr+"-"+mn+"-"+dy;
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd",
                                            Locale.ENGLISH);
try{
Date book_published = df.parse(book_date);
}catch(...){...}
```

and it shows me error like :

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc, published) VALUES('skd flakj','klsdjf askj','kl jasdklfj kl','kls djfklj f' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

Please help me figure out what is the problem here.

Comment: Does one of your values have a stray single quote?  You would avoid a whole lot of trouble by using parameter binding instead of concatenating the values directly in your SQL string.

Comment: [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`desc` is not a particularly good column name because it's a reserved word in MySQL. I'm not sure if this is the only issue here but you may want to try surrounding `desc` with ticks, like so:

```
String sql = "INSERT into books(`name`, `isbn`, `author`, `category`, `desc`, `published`) VALUES('"+name+"','"+isbn+"','"+author+"','"+category+"', '"+desc+"','"+book_published+"')";
```

It's good practice anyway.

Edit: and as others have mentioned, prepared statements are safer when saving untrusted input to a database.

Comment: thanx @josh i got  it :)

Answer (score 3):

Your code is prone to SQL injection attacks due to use of normal query statements. To secure your query use preparedstatement.

As per your query issue, DESC is a reserved word. So you can't use it as column name.View [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) for complete list of reserved words.

Answer (score 1):

desc is a reserved word for MySQL, which means u can just use it plainly.

To use it without getting an error from MySQL, u should use ` surround the reserved word.

Ps: u SQL statement may suffer from SQL injection if using user-inputed parameters, attackers can use it to get control of ur system.Maybe u should try to hv a look on this one.

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet